# Issues with grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables response_archive 27 000 000 rows, and airports which consist of 4 000 rows.

Fields that im trying to select:

- response_archive.min(price)
- response_archive.avg(price)
- response_archive.year_week <- (group by, indexed)
- response_archive.from (joined with airport.IATA)
- response_archive.to (joined with airport.IATA)
- response_archive.from and response_archive.to cannot be the same.
- response_archive.year_week should be within a span, as shown in the query.

I'm having issues with the grouping, i cannot group by response_archive.year_week and at the same time get the minimum/average price.

This is my current query, it's far from optimal, and takes about 90 seconds to perform.

```
SELECT
    `from`,
    `to`,
    year_week,
    min(price) min_price,
    round(AVG(price)) avg_price
  FROM response_archive
   INNER JOIN airports AS `f` ON (f.IATA = `from`)
   INNER JOIN airports AS `t` ON (t.IATA = `to`)
 WHERE
    year_week < '1310' AND
    year_week > '1210' AND
    returntrip = 1 AND
    adults = 1 AND
    children = 0 AND
    `price` < 70000 AND
    `price` > 80 AND
    f.SweCity = 'Stockholm' AND
    t.CountryCode = 'US'
GROUP BY year_week
ORDER BY year_week;
```

Current results:

```
from   to     year_week min   avg
STO    NYC    1211      3552  6311
ARN    LAX    1212      3097  6496
STO    NYC    1213      3532  7379
ARN    NYC    1214      3584  6635
STO    LAX    1215      3523  5907
STO    FLL    1216      3559  5698
STO    NYC    1217      3642  5919
```

Except that the min / avg are incorrect.

Comparing if the first value is correct:

```
SELECT
    min(price) min,
    '3532' min_expected,
    round(avg(price)) avg,
    '7379' avg_expected
FROM
    response_archive
WHERE
    `from` = 'STO' AND
    `to` = 'NYC' AND
    year_week = '1213' AND
    returntrip = 1 AND
    adults = 1 AND
    children = 0 AND
    `price` < 70000 AND
    `price` > 80;
```

Correct result:

```
min     min_exp avg     avg_exp
3532    3532    5955    7379
```

Can someone point me in a direction or explain why it's not giving me the results i want.

Comment: what is the point of temp table x ?

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with the results? When you use an aggregate function with `GROUP BY`, it calculates the min and average just for each group. Is that not what you want?

Comment: You should include `from` and `to` in your `group by` clause. Also, your query is unnecessarily complicated, you don't need to use subqueries.

Comment: 1149 1149 2582 2807, is the result of 
"SELECT min(price) min, '1149' expected_min, round(avg(price)) avg, '2807' expected_avg FROM response_archive WHERE `from` = 'ARN' AND `to` = 'CHQ' AND year_week = '1213'
AND returntrip = 1 AND adults = 1 AND children = 0 AND `price` < 70000 AND `price` > 80;"

Thats what it should have been on 'Expected results' line 3, this query was made as a comparesion to see if the query produce the results i want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your query simplified, and with the missing `GROUP BY` fields added:

```
SELECT
    `from`,
    `to`,
    year_week,
    min(price) min_price,
    round(AVG(price)) avg_price
  FROM response_archive
   INNER JOIN airports AS `f` ON (f.IATA = `from`)
   INNER JOIN airports AS `t` ON (t.IATA = `to`)
 WHERE
    year_week < '1310' AND
    year_week > '1210' AND
    returntrip = 1 AND
    adults = 1 AND
    children = 0 AND
    `price` < 70000 AND
    `price` > 80 AND
    f.CountryCode = 'SE' AND
    t.CountryCode = 'US'
GROUP BY `from`, `to`, year_week
ORDER BY year_week;
```

Comment: I only want to show the cheapest and the average price from a from f.CountryCode to t.CountryCode grouped on year_weeks. Look at my 'Expected results' where its all propperly formatted but the prices are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the table x and put the condition in the external where. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    `from`,
    `to`,
    year_week,
    min(price) min_price,
    round(AVG(price)) avg_price     
FROM
    response_archive AS r
        INNER JOIN airports AS `f` ON (f.IATA = `from`)
        INNER JOIN airports AS `t` ON (t.IATA = `to`),
WHERE
    r.year_week < '1310' AND
    r.year_week > '1210'        
    returntrip = 1 AND
    adults = 1 AND
    children = 0 AND
    `price` < 70000 AND
    `price` > 80 AND
    f.CountryCode = 'SE' AND
    t.CountryCode = 'US'
group by `from`,`to`, year_week
```

Comment: I want it to group on the year_week, and only show from and to on the cheapest, however i would also like to show the average price for that year_week.

Comment: This is exactly what the above query does! In your first query there are two more conditions (`f.SweCity = 'Stockholm' AND t.CountryCode = 'US'`) that are not in the second one. These conditions may distort average and minimum calculation.